# how to create schema for element whose name will change at runtime

Tags: xml, xsd

I have to create schema for following

```
 <Root>
      <users>
        <user1>
           <element1/>
           <element2/>
        </user1>
        <user2>
           <element1/>
           <element2/>
       </user2>
     </users> 
    </Root>
```

Elements user and user1 are dynamic and there can be n number of users in xml and other elements remain the same.

could someone help me in creating schema for this ??

Comment: You mean they can have different names?

Comment: yes they can have different names

Answer (score 1):

Make the `users` element contain an arbitrary number of `user` elements.  Don't try to make them unique by giving each user element a different name.  Just as in your favorite programming language you store a collection of 500 integers in an array of integers, and not in 500 integer variables named int001, int002, int003, ... int500.

Work with the technology, not against it.

Comment: Well spoken. @shailesh91082, if you want to number your items, use an attribute to do it: `<user index="1"><element index="1" /><element index="2" /></user>`.  Then your schema only needs to define `Root`, `users`, `user`, `element` and `@index`.

Comment: Hello, your answer sounds ok, but i was looking to use something like xsd:any to resolve this, do you have any clue ??